# Doubling the Size of a C++ Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The following snippet of code is my attempt to increase the size of an array by a factor of two. I am having several problems with it. Most importantly, should I be calling delete on my original array?

```
void enlarge(int *array, int* dbl  int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       dbl[i] = array[i];
    delete array;
    array = dbl;
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < size*2; i++)` that line will go out of bounds of your original array. Surely you only want to copy as many items as the original array?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: Any particular reason for not using a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)?

Comment: You need declare `array` as a reference to a pointer if you want to modify it from outside the function.

Comment: also, the line `array = double;` does nothing, as you are changing a local copy of `array`.

Comment: Changing the question to match the answers somewhat invalidates the answers.

Comment: Where to you allocate the new array?  Most of the functionality in your `enlarge` function can be replaced by `std::copy`.

Answer (score 7):

You have a few problems:

- Modifying `array` only modifies the local copy of the pointer. You need to take a reference-to-pointer if you want the modification to be observed by the calling code.
- You need to use `delete[]` when deleting things allocated with `new[]`.
- You attempt to copy too many items, and in so doing you overrun the original array.

---

```
void enlarge(int *& array, int size) {
//                ^
// Use a reference to a pointer.

    int *dbl = new int[size*2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    //                  ^
    // Iterate up to size, not size*2.
        dbl[i] = array[i];
    }
    delete[] array;
    //    ^
    // Use delete[], not delete.
    array = dbl;
}
```

---

However, I would strongly suggest using `std::vector<int>` instead; it will automatically resize as necessary and this is completely transparent to you.

Answer (score 1):

keyword double cannot be used as variable name, and previous array must be deleted before new allocation get assigned to same pointer, and loop should copy size no of items from prev array (not 2 * size)

```
void enlarge(int **array, int size) {
    int *d = new int[size*2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       d[i] = *array[i];
    delete [] *array;
    *array = d;
}
```

if previous array was int *arr, and size is the currentsize of the array arr, call should be as: `enlarge(&arr, size)`